# Запуск redis в docker

Tags: php, docker, redis

Есть бэкенд написанный на lumen(laravel), который подключается к redis. Когда запускаю локальный php и локальный redis, то все работает. Когда запускаю через докер выдает ошибку: `Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]`. Сборка php (Dockerfile):

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update \
&& chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
&& chmod -R 777 /var/www/html

RUN pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis
```

Файл docker-compose.yml:

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
    - 127.0.0.1:80:80
    volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
    - ./docker/config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./docker/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    links:
      - php-fpm

  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php-fpm
    volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html

  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:6379:6379
    logging:
      driver: none
```

В чем может быть проблема? Может я какой-то порт не открыл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В контейнере php адрес 127.0.0.1 это закрытый localhost контейнера php при стандартном драйвере сети  докера bridge. Попробуйте поменять tcp://120.0.0.1:6379 на tcp://redis:6379 в конфигах php. Проброс ports в редисе можно убрать.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все заработало)

Comment: Извините, не знаете ли вы ответ на данный вопрос ?https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1151095/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%b0-docker-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5