# Два docker приложения на одном сервере

Tags: docker

Есть два приложения на docker контейнерах.Запускаю оба приложения на `127.0.0.1` но на разных портах. Когда пытаюсь с помощью `curl` обратиться из одного приложения в другое (например из `127.0.0.1:80` в `127.0.0.1:81`) то обращение не происходит. Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне поднять два приложения на одном сервере, чтобы они могли обмениваться данными? Может есть какие-то ограничения у localhost? docker-compose файл одного из приложений (у другого приложения все аналогично кроме порта):

```
services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:81:80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./docker/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    links:
      - php-fpm

  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php-fpm
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
```

Comment: Поскольку запускаете на одном сервере, из одного контейнера в другой вы можете обратиться по container-ip:port, port это внутренний порт, на котором запущено приложение в контейнере.

Comment: @Bakhuss, а как мне узнать `container-ip:port`

Comment: docker inspect container-name, в списке будет ip контейнера. port это тот порт, на котором запущено ваше приложение внутри контейнера.

Answer (score 1):

два контейнера это 2 виртуальные машины, а это в свою очередь значит они изолированы. в каждом контейнере localhost свой, а не вашей машины на котором запущен DockerHub. Так что советую настраивать приложения с учетом они расположены на разных машинах со всеми IP и именами.

Comment: Как я могу узнать их ip адреса?

Comment: по вашему IP адресу вашей машины а не контейнера. Понимаете ваше приложение подключается к другому приложению, оно не знает что оно в контейнере.  Что вы делаете когда вашему приложению нужны данные с google.com ....

Comment: Не совсем вас понял, если честно. в docker-compose файле я перекидываю порты `127.0.0.1:81:80` и `127.0.0.1:80:80`. Т.е. получается когда обращаюсь к порту `81` на 'localhost' получаю одно приложение, когда обращаюсь к `80`, то другое приложение. Я понимаю что они изолированы, но не понимаю как обратиться к другому приложению

Comment: Не думайте что они рядом и всё. Вы подняли один сервер где-то и второй. Из вне как достучаться до каждого? стаким подходом у вас не будет проблем

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете или построить общую сеть, настроив сетки и ip адреса.

Либо сделать общую сеть между двумя проектами: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects

Еще можно настроить только одну сеть у одного приложения (с которого будут идти запросы). Адрес хоста будет маска сети с едицой в кноце. И сможете обращаться к своему севрису по его порту на хосте, через iphost:port

Answer (score 1):

Очень рекомендую почитать, как докер строит сети и как с ним можно работать.
Если совсем по харду то вот примерчик

1. для начала создаете подсеть:

```
docker network create --subnet 172.10.0.0/16 custom_net
```

2. далее одно из приложений

```
version: '3'

services:

    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - 80:80
        networks:
            default:
                ipv4_address: 172.10.0.102
  
    php-fpm:
        image: php:7.2-fpm
        extra_hosts:
            - "nginx.app2:172.10.0.102"
            - "nginx.app1:172.10.0.101"


networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: custom_net
```

3. далее другое приложение:

```
version: '3'

services:

    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - 81:80
        networks:
            default:
                ipv4_address: 172.10.0.101
  
    php-fpm:
        image: php:7.2-fpm
        extra_hosts:
            - "nginx.app2:172.10.0.102"
            - "nginx.app1:172.10.0.101"

networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: custom_net
```

Как видно разница лишь в портах, которые контейнеры nginx отдают наружу и в присвоении статических ip для nginx.
Теперь можно попробовать войти в какой-либо из контейнеров  php и выполнить

```
curl http://nginx.app1
curl http://nginx.app2
```

NOTE: в примере nginx не смотрит на php! т.е. в ответе curl будет просто страница приветствия nginx.

Comment: Есть разница в плане настройки сети между `3` и `3.5` версией docker-compose?

Comment: Вот это не подскажу